# Printing the response content body when using curl to post data

Tags: ubuntu, curl

I'm using the command below on ubuntu:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"foo":"bar"}'  http://localhost:8888/
```

The following is the response received:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 3
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Server: TornadoServer/2.1
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

So my question is; how do I post using curl and print out the response content body?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It finally worked for me with this command:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id":100}' http://localhost/api/postJsonReader.do
```

Comment: ^ that depends on the service at the other end.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to replace `-d '{"foo":"bar"}'` with `-d 'foo=bar'`? You shouldn't have to do anything special to receive the response content body as long as the request succeeds.