# calling a http post api via curl with proxy server successfully but no content

Tags: http, curl

I am calling a http post api via curl, and through proxy server.
how ever, call successful, response code `200` and Content-Length: `157`. But no any body or content.

my curl cmd:

```
curl -v -I -x proxyServer:Port -X POST apiUrl

response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Jul 2019 10:58:01 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 157
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing the response content body when using curl to post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870138/printing-the-response-content-body-when-using-curl-to-post-data)

Comment: thx..when i remove -v -I , it works.. but dont understand why